# How to make 3 responsive col in bootstrap 3 with 20px margin between cols

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanna make 3 responsive col with bootstrap 3 that have 20px gap between them ,how?

Comment: i cant give between them gap

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="height: 20px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="height: 360px;background-color:green"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="height: 360px;background-color:black"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="height: 360px;background-color:blue"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```